# Set conditional formatting for excel in office.js

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-office, office-js

I need a way to set conditional formatting in an [office.js](/questions/tagged/office.js) add-in.

Currently thinking I might be able to use VBA to set it based on the cell value that the add-in sets - but it would be really nice to be able to do this directly from within office.js.

I am looking for some creative workarounds until Microsoft implements this natively within the add-in.

Comment: Conditional formatting code examples: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/excel/excel-add-ins-conditional-formatting.md

Answer (score 5):

Based on your (and many other developers' feedback), we're announcing the preview of Excel API 1.6 at Build 2017 right now, which includes support for conditional formatting. Office 365 Insider builds with support for Excel API 1.6 will be available later this month.

I built a snippet that shows you the basics of those APIs, which you can look at in our new Script lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab). Simply install the Script Lab add-in, then choose "import" in the navigation menu and import the following gist: https://gist.github.com/TristanD-MSFT/80920d57bf587bd859ff62afb2b7c673

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time we do not have support for setting conditional formatting via Office.js yet, but we will consider adding support for this for further updates we are making to the API.

Thanks,
Philip, Software Engineer on the Office Extensibility team

Answer (score 0):

As Philip said, conditional formatting is not available out of the box (as of ExcelApi 1.2).  As far as a creative workaround goes, depending on the size of your range, you could do something like this.

The basic idea is to create a binding over the desired range. Then add a data change listener and re-apply the formatting every time that a change has occurred.

To create the binding, something as simple as this will do:

```js
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromPromptAsync(Office.BindingType.Matrix, {id:'MyBinding'});
```

Now comes the interesting part, the eventing:

```js
var binding;

Office.context.document.bindings.getByIdAsync('MyBinding', function(result) {
    if (result.status === "succeeded") {
        binding = result.value;
        binding.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged, formatData);
    } else {
        console.log(result.error.message);
    }
});

function formatData() {
    // First, disable the binding that was previously created, or else
    // setting formatting will also trigger data changed event.
    binding.removeHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged);

    Excel.run(function(ctx) {
        var range = ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem('MyBinding').getRange();
        range.load("values");
        return ctx.sync().then(function() {
            for (var row = 0; row < range.values.length; row++) {
                for (var col = 0; col < range.values[0].length; col++) {
                    var cellValue = range.values[row][col];
                    var color;
                    if (cellValue < 30) {
                        color = "red";
                    } else if (cellValue < 65) {
                        color = "orange"; 
                    } else {
                        color = "green";
                    }
                    range.getCell(row, col).format.fill.color = color;
                }
            }
        })
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function() {
        // Re-enable the event:
        binding.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged, formatData);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps as a temporary workaround!

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: Thanks for replying Mike, unfortunately this won't work for me as I need the conditional formatting to be set in the workbook so it works without the add-in.

Comment: Please add Conditional Formatting. It is impossible to use the binding change for large range change tracking.

Comment: Conditional Formatting is slated for ExcelApi 1.5.  You can see the design docs here:  https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_1.4_OpenSpec.  It is listed as 1.4 in that document, but it has been moved to 1.5 (unless it ends up being 1.6, just for purposes of us shipping 1.5 faster; but I know that the vast bulk of the conditional-formatting functionality has already been coded up)

Comment: @CloudXu, see my comment above